# Why is $\frac{d(x^n)}{d(x)}=nx^{n-1}$

Tags: derivatives

So I was thinking about what I have learnt and I realised that I kind of took the derivative of a function for granted. So I did some research as I wanted to find out how this was discovered and I stumbled upon [this](http://www.storyofmathematics.com/17th_newton.html).

More specially, here is a passage from it:

> Without going into too much complicated detail, Newton (and his contemporary Gottfried Leibniz independently) calculated a derivative function $f'(x)$ which gives the slope at any point of a function $f(x)$. This process of calculating the slope or derivative of a curve or function is called differential calculus or differentiation (or, in Newton’s terminology, the “method of fluxions” - he called the instantaneous rate of change at a particular point on a curve the "fluxion", and the changing values of x and y the "fluents"). For instance, the derivative of a straight line of the type $f(x) = 4x$ is just $4$; the derivative of a squared function $f(x) = x^2$ is $2x$; the derivative of cubic function $f(x) = x^3$ is $3x^2$.

I was wondering if anyone could explain (or point me to a resource) the "complicated details" (or hopefully, a rigorous proof) of how the derivative function $f'(x)$ was discovered?

Comment: So you want the method that Newton or Leibniz used?  Or do you want a modern proof?

Comment: Would both be too much to ask? :P

Comment: I'll give you the proof.  Maybe someone else will research how the founders did it.

Comment: This kind of thing has *got* to be in your calculus textbook.

Comment: It seems very likely to me that they used nothing more than the binomial formula, which was known to both. It is also worth noting that neither were particularly interested in rigorous proof, and it is very easy to convince oneself that this derivative is true.

Comment: Finding the slope of the tangent line to $y=x^n$ was known to Fermat and Descartes.

Comment: @AndréNicolas the slope of the secant is $\frac{(x+h)^n - x^n}{h} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k (x+h)^{n-1-k}$ but how did they justify the slope was $n x^{n-1}$ without letting $h \to 0$ ?

Comment: [Simply](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595531/can-0-0-be-allowed-if-it-can-be-defined)...

Comment: They both essentially used the fact that a line is tangent to a polynomial if the line meets the polynomial in a double root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I introduce the derivative in my first semester calculus, I show my students the following relatively straightforward proof of the so-called "power rule".

Notice primarily that for all positive integers $n$ and all real numbers $a$ we have:

\begin{align}
(x-a)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-1-i}
&=x\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-1-i}-a\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-1-i} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i+1}a^{n-1-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-1-i+1} \\
&=x^{(n-1)+1}a^{n-1-(n-1)}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^{i+1}a^{n-1-i}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-i}+x^0a^{n-0}\right) \\
&=x^na^0+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-i}-x^0a^n \\
&=x^n-a^n
\end{align}

Now remember that one way of defining the derivative of function $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is given by the following limit provided it exists:

$$f'(a):=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

Now we'll use the above definition of the derivative together with our work at the beginning to derive the function $f(x)=x^n$ at $x=a$:

\begin{align*}
f'(a)&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} \\
&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-1-i}}{x-a}
=\lim_{x\to a}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^ia^{n-1-i} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ia^{n-1-i}
=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{i+n-1-i}
=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1} \\
&=na^{n-1}
\end{align*}

In particular for every real number $a$ we have $f'(a)=na^{n-1}$.  Hence as a function $\frac{d(x^n)}{dx}=f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ as we wanted.

**Note:** Historically a similar proof was used, but that proof relies on "infinitely small numbers," a concept which most mathematicians agree was not well-founded at the time.  This proof is considered rigorous, although I have left some words out (you should be able to fill them in as long as you know your limit laws!).

Comment: Amazing answer thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! @YellowPillow